# SQL Count Intra-Group Agreement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of OCR-type results. We don't perform our own, the domain is such that it's not worth it. Instead we run our images against 3 separate third party OCR APIs and store the results. We normalize a bunch of stuff, but the only fields relevant to my question are those defined in the following table:

```sql
create table OcrResults (
    file_id int not null,
    ocr_result nvarchar(10) null,
    processor nvarchar(20)
);
```

Here is some sample data to play with:

```sql
insert OcrResults (file_id, ocr_result, processor)
values
(1, null, 'a'),
(1, 'a-missed', 'b'), -- a disagrees with b and c
(1, 'a-missed', 'c'),

(2, 'c-not-run', 'a'), -- agreement: c not run
(2, 'c-not-run', 'b'), -- agreement: c not run

(3, null, 'a'), -- agreement: no processor found text
(3, null, 'b'), -- agreement: no processor found text
(3, null, 'c'), -- agreement: no processor found text

(4, 'experiment-with-processor-d', 'd'), -- agreement, sort of, these one-offs aren't interesting and can be discarded

(5, 'agreed', 'a'),
(5, 'agreed', 'b'),
(5, 'agreed', 'b'),

(6, null, 'a'),
(6, 'a-failed-at-first', 'a'),
(6, 'a-failed-at-first', 'b'),
(6, 'a-failed-at-first', 'c');
```

In practice each file is pretty much run once against all three of our major processors, but there is no uniqueness constraint on the table, a given file *might* be repeatedly run against the same processor (usually giving back the same result, although not always if the processor updates its AI model). Further a given file might *not* be run against all three.  This table simply records what we did and what the results were.

I can't figure out how to get a query that will perform the intra-grouping analysis. I want:

1. A count of the files where all the processors that were used on it agreed.
2. A count of the files where all the processors that were used on it disagreed.
3. A count of the files where processors a, b agree, but c was run *and* disagrees.
4. A count of the files where processors b, c agree, but a was run *and* disagrees.
5. A count of the files where processors a, c agree, but b was run *and* disagrees.
6. I don't *really* want to hard code the list of processors in case we add or remove processors moving forward. This means that 3, 4, and 5 above needs to handle the situation where there *are* 4 processors, a and b agree, but c disagrees and a and b agree but d disagrees (and the other wasn't run). If it must be manually handled I will accept that answer as long as the query fails or makes it obvious that I need to update the query (returns a list or row indicating a heretofore unseen grouping).

The closest I have gotten is:

```sql
WITH IgnoreRepeats AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT file_id, ocr_result, processor
    FROM OcrResults (NOLOCK)
), Agreements AS (
    SELECT file_id, ocr_result, STRING_AGG(processor, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY processor) in_agreement
    FROM IgnoreRepeats
    GROUP BY fileuuid, vehicleplate
)
SELECT in_agreement, COUNT(*) 
FROM Agreements
GROUP BY processors
ORDER BY 2
```

This largely answers my question about the intra-group agreement, but the numbers don't add up, and so I know it's missing cases where only one was run (so it doesn't really count). I'm fairly certain this query will need a group and pivot, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Is file_id = #6 consider an agreement among all or not?

Comment: also, in case you add processor x,y,z, how does one solve #6, what kind of possibilities is interesting? any disagreements is enough?

Comment: @siggemannen Excellent question, sorry my question didn't include that: I'd be happy with an answer that chose to handle that either way.

Comment: I'd also be ok filtering out any cases where the same processor was run multilpe times with differing results

Comment: I have significant freedom here, it's a reporting query on a table with 4.5M rows, so even several thousand instances here would be a rounding error.

Comment: Desired results would help clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very quick batch of SQL that you can probably use to get what you need:

```sql
WITH ocr_results AS (
    SELECt  *
    FROM    (
        VALUES
        (1, NULL, 'a'),
        (1, 'a-missed', 'b'), -- a disagrees with b and c
        (1, 'a-missed', 'c'),
        
        (2, 'c-not-run', 'a'), -- agreement: c not run
        (2, 'c-not-run', 'b'), -- agreement: c not run
        
        (3, NULL, 'a'), -- agreement: no processor found text
        (3, NULL, 'b'), -- agreement: no processor found text
        (3, NULL, 'c'), -- agreement: no processor found text
        
        (4, 'experiment-with-processor-d', 'd'), -- agreement, sort of, these one-offs aren't interesting and can be discarded
        
        (5, 'agreed', 'a'),
        (5, 'agreed', 'b'),
        (5, 'agreed', 'b'),
        
        (6, NULL, 'a'),
        (6, 'a-failed-at-first', 'a'),
        (6, 'a-failed-at-first', 'b'),
        (6, 'a-failed-at-first', 'c')
    ) v (file_id, ocr_result ,processor)
    )
select  file_id
,   SUM(flag) AS successes
,   COUNT(*)  AS totals
,   MAX(CASE WHEN flag = 0 AND rnk = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS firstFail
,   MAX(CASE WHEN flag = 0 AND rnk = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS secondFail
,   MAX(CASE WHEN flag = 0 AND rnk = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS thirdFail
,   MAX(CASE WHEN flag = 0 AND rnk = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS forthFail
,   MAX(CASE WHEN processor = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ARan
,   MAX(CASE WHEN processor = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BRan
,   MAX(CASE WHEN processor = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CRan
,   MAX(CASE WHEN processor = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DRan
,   MAX(CASE WHEN processor = 'E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ERan
from    (
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY file_id, processor ORDER BY case when ocr_result is null then 0 ELSE 1 END DESC) AS sort
    ,   DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY file_id ORDER BY processor) AS rnk
    ,   case when ocr_result is null then 0 ELSE 1 END as flag
    ,   *
    FROM    ocr_results
    ) x
WHERE   sort = 1 -- remove dups
group by file_id
```

Output:

| file_id | successes | totals | firstFail | secondFail | thirdFail | forthFail | ARan | BRan | CRan | DRan | ERan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

I use various grouping techniques to get the data you're looking for. It's not super-dynamic, but you can either copy paste whatever else you need or build the rest of the query dynamically from the list of operators you have.

Comment: This is as close as I'll get, I think.